# How call Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have code (see below) in my webpage. With below code i get two flash mp3 players on the web page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Contents/swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function stop() {
    document.getElementById("myId1").SetVariable("player:jsStop", "");}
    </script>    

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center;">

<tr>
<td>

<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("Contents/player_mp3_maxi.swf", "myId1", "250", "20", "9.0.0", false, false, {menu: "false",flashvars: "mp3=Contents/Sleep Away.mp3"}, false);
</script>

<div id="myId1" 
style="position: relative; width: 250px; height: 20px; ">
</div>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("Contents/player_mp3_maxi.swf", "myId2", "250", "20", "9.0.0", false, false, {menu: "false",flashvars: "mp3=Contents/Kalimba.mp3"}, false);
</script>                

<div id="myId2" 
style="position: relative; width: 250px; height: 20px; ">
</div>

<br />              
<a href="javascript:stop()">Stop</a>        

</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works fine and all i need now that only one flash mp3 player should play the audio at one time.  For example if i click on flash plyer 2 then falsh player 1 should stop and vice versa.  I can stop flash players with click event with below code but this is not fulfilling what i need.

I have put below function in head tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function stop() {
    document.getElementById("myId1").SetVariable("player:jsStop", "");}
    </script>
```

and this in body tag

```
<a href="javascript:stop()">Stop</a>
```

Can please any friend tell me that how can i achive what i need with above stop function.  Or where should i put this code so when i click on fash player 2 then flash player 1 should stop playing audio.

Answer (score 0):

Make only one of the players start on page load.
Then, make a handler that will be ran on a click on one of the players. If the click was originated from player1, them stop it and start player2 (and viceversa).